# Is it my instructor's interface that's the problem?

Tags: java, interface

I have an assignment to make an implementation of an interface called "CarInterface". My class will be called "Car", and it is tested in another class called "CarTester".

I am having a small problem with one of the methods in the interface, however.

This method is called "equals", and it accepts a CarInterface parameter. In the CarTester main, it seems that he wants this method to check if the make, model, color, and year data are the same (only these attributes). Despite that, CarInterface does not have any methods for getting that information! Now I am at a standstill and contemplating if his interface is the problem or not.

I first thought it would be alright to cast the CarInterface parameter as Object, and then pass it on to this.equals(...). That's when I realized something was wrong here.

(Here is a snippet from the interface code)
(The interface doesn't even have a method for getting the VIN)

```java
/**
     * Checks to see if the calling Car and the argument Car have the same state except for the VIN
     * Precondition: Both the calling Car and argument Car are fully initialized
     * Postcondition: no change
     * @param pCarObject
     * @return
     * returns true if the calling Car and the argument Car have the same state except for the VIN, else returns false
     */
    public boolean equals(CarInterface pCarObject);
```

Here is the full interface code:

```java
package interfacePackage;
public interface CarInterface 
{
    /**
     * This module changes the color of the car to the color of the argument.
     * Precondition: a state variable that holds the color of the Car
     * Postcondition: The value of the color of the car is now set to the value contained in the parameter.
     * @param pColor
     */
    public void paint(String pColor);

    /**
     * Fills the car fuel tank
     * Precondition: Car has a fuel tank
     * Postcondition: Car's fuel tank is full
     * @return
     * Amount of fuel used to fill tank
     */
    public double fillTank();

    /**
     * Adds fuel to the car's fuel tank
     * Precondition: Car has a fuel tank
     * Postcondition: Car's fuel tank may have added fuel
     * @return
     * Negative number indicating the amount of fuel the tank will still take
     * Positive value of the amount of argument fuel not used, if 0 it just filled the tank
     */
    public double fillTank(double pFuel);

    /**
     * Converts the Car object's state variables to a String representation
     * Precondition: All state variables are initialized
     * Postcondition: no change
     * @return
     * year, make, model, color, VIN
     */
    public String toString();

    /**
     * Checks to see if the calling Car and the argument Car have the same state except for the VIN
     * Precondition: Both the calling Car and argument Car are fully initialized
     * Postcondition: no change
     * @param pCarObject
     * @return
     * returns true if the calling Car and the argument Car have the same state except for the VIN, else returns false
     */
    public boolean equals(CarInterface pCarObject);

    /**
     * drives the Car predefined distance and speed.
     * Precondition: Car's trip state variables have been initialized
     * Postcondition: Car's fuel is reduced proportional to the distance and speed driven or depleted if the distance and speed are too great. odometer and trip odometer are updated with the miles traveled added.
     * @return
     * true if the car travels the distance with fuel remaining, false if the car runs out of fuel
     */
    public boolean driveCar();

    /**
     * gets trip odometer
     * Precondition: none
     * Postcondition: no change of state
     * @return
     * double value of trip odometer to nearest tenth of mile
     */
    public double getTripOdometer();

    /**
     * sets trip odometer mileage to 0.0
     * Precondition: none
     * Postcondition: trip odometer set to 0.0
     */
    public void clearTripOdometer();

    /**
     * gets odometer mileage
     * Precondition: none
     * Postcondition: no change to state
     * @return
     * double value of odometer to nearest tenth of mile
     */
    public double getOdometer();

    /**
     * retrieves fuel level in gallons
     * Precondition: fuel level is initialized
     * Postcondition: no change is state
     * @return
     * fuel level in gallons with decimal values
     */
    public double getFuelLevel();

    /**
     * Car's state is set to hold the speed of travel and distance to travel at that speed
     * Precondition: none
     * Postcondition: Car's state holds information on distance to travel and speed to travel
     * @param pAverageSpeed
     * @param pDrivingDistance
     */
    public void setUpTrip(double pAverageSpeed, double pDrivingDistance);



}
```

Comment: Look at ToString... it is a poorly-written spec though.

Comment: Are there any other subclasses of `CarInterface` that could potentially equal a `Car` object? If not, you could consider casting `pCarObject` to a `Car` to ensure that only a `Car` can equal a `Car`.

Comment: That does indeed seem weird. Especially because this introduces potential confusion with the standard `equals` method defined in `Object`. Anyway: Only your instructor will be able to actually help you with that.

Comment: There are not any other subclasses of CarInterface. Despite that, I still feel like that equals method might as well be default. Another implementation's instance could possibly have the same characteristics as a `Car` instance, but they will never be equal with how things are setup. I know there ISN'T another implementation, but I still believe that students shouldn't be exposed to this practice.

Comment: Just look up how a standard override of `Object#equals()` looks like. It is very similar to what you need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it looks like the `equals(CarInterface pCarObject)` method is supposed to work off of unpacking `pCarObject`'s information present in `toString()` from the interface, drop the VIN, and compare with the information from that. It's a nasty way to do it, but it works *I guess*.

Building upon what @racraman said, something like this will **never** fly in a professional context (at least, *should* never fly). A `toString()` is exclusively for making a human-readable output, and is not intended for transmitting data internally. Even a painful `getDetails()` method that returns everything in a cryptic array is more acceptable than using a `toString()`.

The ideal way to handle this is to use getters and setters so you only spend time getting exactly what you need, no more, and no less. This is especially useful if a getter needs to do some amount of work to transform the value(s) into the output, so you don't waste time transforming an output that just gets dropped.

Comment: I guess I'm blind 'cause I don't see where it is suggested to read data from the `toString()` result.

Comment: Fully concur with “it’s a nasty way to do it”.   Since we have students here, it is worth emphasising a general rule : use toString ONLY for human readability - the output of toString should never be used for business logic (so never parsed, etc)

Answer (score 1):

An interface defines a *contract*, not an implementation.

If the contract requires the comparison of state (make, model, color, etc), there’s nothing stopping you from defining those fields in your Car class, which is an implementation of the CarInterface contract, so it can fulfil the contract.

And that’s what you need to do; declare fields (make, model, etc) for state implied by the interface. You don’t have to define accessor methods (getters), but it seems reasonable to do so.

Implementing an interface doesn’t restrict you to only having methods of that interface, and it says nothing about any fields the class may or may not have.

Comment: Except that the method explicitly states that the parameter is a `CarInterface`, so you'll only have methods in the interface available to you, no matter how you implement it.

Comment: @Bohemian♦ That's not the problem. The problem has to do with how `CarInterface` provides no methods for checking VIN, model, make, etc. Sure, I can check if the parameter is instanceof `Car`, but I know that is bad practice because there _could_ be other classes that implement `CarInterface`.

Comment: @AaronPerzan hmmm. I think your instructor should go back to school himself. Even the design of the interface is flawed. IMHO CarInterface should have accessor methods and there should be a `Fueler` interface that has a `fuel(Fuelable fueledCar)` for example because not all cars can be fuelled (eg Teslas).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Bohemian's answer.

You Car object can only be equal to another Car object (usually).

It is fair enough that if the object passed in is not a Car, you can reject it straight away.  This is very common for default Java equals implementations.
One you know the other object is a Car, you can then cast it to a Car and get the year, make, model and colour of the other Car and compare them.

I don't see any mention of using toString for object comparison.

Comment: Every assignment of this style that I've seen has required the ability to compare not only a `Car` but also a `Truck` or `Motorcycle` at the same time.